# Using Gradle plugin configuration properties at the evaluation phase

Tags: java, plugins, groovy, gradle, build.gradle

I'm writing my own gradle plugin and want to define an additional Copy task.
What I do is:

```
myPlugin {
    scriptsDir = "otherDir"
}

class MyPluginExtension {
    String scriptsDir = "scripts";
}    

class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

   @Override
   void apply(Project project) {
      project.extensions.create("myPlugin", MyPluginExtension)

      project.task("myDistCopy", type: Copy) {
         .....
         from(project.myPlugin.scriptDir) {
            into('bin')
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Unfortunately the files are still copied from the "scripts" folder instead of "otherDir". It seems that the extension properties are not set at the evaluation phase. Do you have any ideas how can I refer to the myPlugin settings in the Copy task?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, extension properties are not set at evaluation phase. As a workaround You can implement a custom task of type `Copy` (extends) and specify property annotated with `@OutputDirectory` - this way You can configure it easily.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I didn't manage to easily implement the task. Do you have some examples? Actually I need read the inputs, I tried the @InputDirectory annotation, but it didn't really work.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any examples :/

Comment: But how would I set those properties annotated with @OutputDirectory from extension properties? thanks

Answer (score 5):

Actually the solution that worked for me turned out to be pretty simple:

```
project.task("myDistCopy", type: Copy) {
     .....
     project.afterEvaluate {
         from(project.myPlugin.scriptDir) {
            into('bin')
         }
     }
  }
```

Comment: In fact, judging from [the Gradle User Guide](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#build_lifecycle_events), this seems to be just the Gradle feature intended for this purpose. Thanks!